# Can't bitwise invert bytearray

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is a small snippet of code:

```
data = bytearray(file.read(1024))
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    data[i] = ~data[i]
```

But for some reason, this doesn't work! I keep getting `ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)` at the line in the for loop. I don't understand, isn't the bitwise inverse of a byte still the same size of a byte??

I added `print type(data[i])` just to see what was going on, and it says `int`!! How can an `int` fit into a byte in python?

Comment: Just wondering, have you opened file in binary format, like open('file', 'rb').

Comment: Yes, its being opened as a binary file. I am using `r+b` to be exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since bytes in bytearray are unsigned, bitwise invert operator will always return a negative int, just add 256 (the max value of a byte) to it:

```
data = bytearray(file.read(1024))
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    data[i] = ~data[i] + 256
```

Comment: `since bytes in bytearray are unsigned, bitwise invert operator will always return a negative int` That's just plain wrong. An 8 bit unsigned byte holds values from 0 to 255, whereas an 8 bit **signed** byte holds values of -128 to 127. You mean `since bytes in bytearray are **signed** ` right?

Comment: Either way it doesn't (or shouldn't) matter, the bits are the same, its just how the most significant bit is interpreted. I **should** be able to just stick the byte in the bytearray regardless if whether or not it is signed or unsigned. Why is byte manipulation so damn hard in python?

Comment: Oh, that is not what  I meant, since there is no bytes in python there's just int floats and they are always signed. What I meant to say is that since they always will be positive they inverse will always be negative so you safely add 256.

Answer (score 0):

Having recently had this problem, my solution was:

```
data[i] = ~data[i] & 0xFF
```